# JPA sync validations before persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa, soap

I have a following problem. I have an AppointmentRequest class that is an entity that looks like this:

```
public class AppointmentRequest implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4075310313280246558L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_Sequence", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "APPOINTMENT_REQUEST_ID", nullable = false)
    private long requestId;
    @Version
    private long version;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long jmbg;
    @OneToOne
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;
```

Timeslot entity:

```
public class TimeSlot {
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP(0)",nullable=false)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="timeSlot")
    private AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest;
```

And here is the EJB code that validates and persists appointmentRequest:

```
validator.slotAvailable(appointmentRequest.getTimeSlot());
entityManager.persist(appointmentRequest);
```

Validator EJB checks if the timeslot is available and if it is the appointmentRequest should be persisted, but if not it throws an exception. The request and response goes trough a SOAP web service, so the service returns true if success, or false if the slot is already booked.

It all works fine when I send the SOAP requests one by one.

However, I made a SOAP client that make multiple threads(to simulate multiple clients) and sends many requests for the same time slot at the same time. In that case multiple appointmentRequest get persisted in one timeslot. 
That 's happening because validations happen asynchronously and validations for multiple threads pass at the same time, so multiple entities get persisted, which shouldn't happen.

How can I resolve this? By adding validation to @Prepersist callback, I got better performance, but still sometimes multiple appointmentRequests get persisted in the same timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

I would just synchronize and take the performance hit:

```
validator.slotAvailable(appointmentRequest.getTimeSlot());

synchronized {
  validator.slotAvailable(appointmentRequest.getTimeSlot());
  entityManager.persist(appointmentRequest);
  entityManager.flush()
}
```